# sequelize insert values into a table with include from another table

Tags: sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize. I have create two table contact and countries.

In contact table I have  `id, name, nationalNumber, and countryId`;

In countries table I have `id, ios2`

I also have other attribute in the table.

In the API users is sending the array like this .

```
[
        {
            "name": "Aftab",
            "mobile_number": "3408906107",
            "name_check": 0,
            "country_iso2": "PK"
        },
        {
            "name": "Numan Jhanger",
            "mobile_number": "3179608039",
            "name_check": "0",
            "country_iso2": "PK"
        },
        {
            "name": "Muhammad Zaki",
            "mobile_number": "3175623123",
            "name_check": 0,
            "country_iso2": "PK"
        },
        {
            "name": "Irshad Khan",
            "mobile_number": "3428890654",
            "name_check": 0,
            "country_iso2": "PK"
        },
]
```

I want to id form countries table based on each item **country_iso2**  and then insert into the table.

here what I tried.

```
async function create(data) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    data.contacts.map(async (item, index) => {
      let ios2 = item.country_iso2;
      delete item.country_iso2;
      await db.filtered_contacts
        .findOrCreate({
          where: { mobile_number: item.mobile_number },
          defaults: { ...item, country_id: 167 },
        })
        .then(([item, created]) => {
          console.log(item); // John
          console.log(created); // true
        });
    });

    resolve("dsds");
  });
}
```

this is working find. I just to get the country id from the table.
I have defined relation and they are working fine.

```
  // countires and filter contact relations
  db.countries.hasMany(db.filtered_contacts, {
    foreignKey: "country_id",
  });
  db.filtered_contacts.belongsTo(db.countries, {
    foreignKey: "country_id",
  });
```

I am new to **sequelize**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple you just have to follow these to insert the records

- First make `countries.findAll()` and get the list of all countries.
  map your received data array and get `ios2` from each item filter
  the record from countries list and store the id in variable or make
  your object respectively.

here is a simple example

```
    const countries-list = countries.findAll();
    const received-date = [ {},{},...];
    received-date.map(item=>{
    let ios2 = item.country_iso2;
    let country = countries-list.filter(function(obj){
       //loop through each object
       for(key in obj){
      //check if object value contains value you are looking for
        if(obj[key].includes(ios2)){
        //add this object to the filtered array
         return obj;
        }
       }
    });
    console.log(country.id)
   //here you can write rest of your code
    })
```